# Find and separate words with first letter of words in my ul list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to find and separate a word that starts with a specific letter?
My English language is not good. Sorry.

I want to find "Milk" and rest of the words that begin with M by using the "M" letter in order to get it.

The code is correct but I want to change x[2] to x[M] for Milk, Machine and Mercedes

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[2].innerHTML;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Machine</li>
  <li>Mercedes</li>

</ul>

<p>Click the button to display the innerHTML of the second li element (index 1).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find` and set a default value if no element was found:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("LI"));
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    (x.find(el => el.innerHTML.toLowerCase().startsWith('m')) || {innerHTML: 'No match'}).innerHTML;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to display the innerHTML of the second li element (index 1).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

For multiple elements, use filter instead. Below is a simple search filter that demonstrates this.

```js
document.getElementById('filter').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const {
    value
  } = document.getElementById('search');
  const resUl = document.querySelector('#demo');
  resUl.innerHTML = '';
  Array.from(document.getElementById('searchList').children).filter(e => e.innerText.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase()))
    .forEach(el => resUl.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true)));
});
```

```html
<ul id="searchList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>



<input id="search" />
<button id="filter">Try it</button>


<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Comment: thank you, but if Have a few words in my list that starts with M, what to do?

Comment: You'd use filter instead of find, then handle the resulting array @ramin.

Answer (score 1):

Use `findIndex` - you also need to convert `x` to an array.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = [...document.getElementsByTagName("LI")];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[x.findIndex(e => e.innerHTML[0] == "M")].innerHTML;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to display the innerHTML of the second li element (index 1).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: thank you, but if Have a few words in my list that starts with M, what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to get all your list items and then [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out those which [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) your desired characters like so.

```js
var prefix = "M";
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var $listItems = $("ul > li");
  var found = $listItems.filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().startsWith(prefix);
  }).clone().get();

  $("#demo").html(found);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Mercedes</li>
  <li>Chocolate</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to display the innerHTML of the second li element (index 1).</p>

<button id="btn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```